# ¿Cómo saber el límite de compresión Gzip?

Tags: httpd

Hola amigos tengo una duda, necesito saber el límite de compresión de Gzip, ya busqué en mi archivo httpf.conf pero al momento de buscar solo me arroja los siguientes datos, ya no me salen más coincidencias:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me dice como tal un límite ¿me podrían orientar en dónde podría encontrar esa información? entiendo que sí esta activada la compresión pero quiero saber cuál es el límite, ayuda por favor :(

Comment: Hola. Disculpa, pero tu pregunta, específica como es, no está muy clara en su formato actual. ¿Qué límite buscas? Cada algoritmo de compresión tiene una implementación y varias aproximaciones (que tardan más o menos tiempo). Para Apache HTTP, él usa la librería disponible, invoca los métodos para comprimir _al-vuelo_ y entregar esos recursos a la petición correspondiente. Y ahí está la duda: no sé a qué límite en la compresión te refieres. Tamaño mínimo o máximo de archivo a comprimir? Grado de compresión (poco, mucho)?

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo me solicitarón la siguiente información
Max Request Workers
Max Connections per Child
Gzip compression limit
Las anteriores si las obtuve pero me falta Gzip compression limit, no me especificaron pero ¿cómo podría saber ambas maneras?me  refiero al tamaño máximo de archivo a comprimir y el grado de compresión

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gzip [no tiene límite](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/469298/compression-utility-max-files-size-limit-unix-linux) per se.

En Apache HTTP, sé que uno usa cosas como

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/javascript
```

y así define qué tipos de archivo se comprimen y cuáles no. Hay [otros parámetros](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_deflate.html) que se pueden definir como DeflateCompressionLevel y tal.

Se puede [validar defensivamente](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49271014/236345) que esté mod_deflate disponible con algo como

```
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
# Insert filters
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml

# Drop problematic browsers
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
```

Peeeeero no recuerdo algo que permita filtrar por tamaño de archivo en Apache. En Nginx, por ejemplo, uno puede definir fácilmente cosas como

```
gzip on;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_http_version 1.0;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_min_length 1100;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_types text/plain text/html text/css application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
```